# Отправка post запроса в vk.com

Tags: curl, php, vkontakte-api

Подскажите пожалуйста, отправляется cURL запрос на адрес, сформированный методом `photos.getWallUploadServer`

```
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array('photo' => '@.$_FILES[photo]; type=image/jpeg'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $postURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data['photo']);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data1 = substr($result, 0, strpos($result, '{'));
$result = str_replace($data1, "", $result);
echo $result;
```

Возвращает `{"server":306709,"photo":"[]","hash":"849fa23e77cce881380f4ed2e588eb59"}`, хотя поле photo не должно быть пустым. Версия cURL 7.19

Comment: @fusion, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1):

Когда в ответ приходит пустой фотослист, это значит, ни что иное как то, что никаких фотографий ты не пытаешься загрузить. Попробуй так:

```
//здесь у нас массив фоток,который ты пытаешься загрузить на сервер, если нужна одна то грузи одну
$post_params = array(
"file1" => "@".dirname(__FILE__)."/itmp/image1.jpg",
"file2" => "@".dirname(__FILE__)."/itmp/image2.jpg",
"file3" => "@".dirname(__FILE__)."/itmp/image3.jpg",
"file4" => "@".dirname(__FILE__)."/itmp/image4.jpg",
"file5" => "@".dirname(__FILE__)."/itmp/image5.jpg"
);
//проверяешь постпарамс есть ли он вообще, тока расскамментируй
//  var_dump($post_params);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $upload_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params);
$result = curl_exec($ch);   
// проверяешь что у тебя в ресалте.

//  var_dump($result);
```

P.S. код полностью 10500% рабочий.

Comment: @AmP, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.